# Deploy ASP.Net MVC solution to Windows 2008

Tags: asp.net-mvc, configuration, iis-7, windows-server-2008

We have a ASP.Net MVC project that runs fine on our developer machines.

When we try and run it on a Windows 2008 machine we get the following error:

Error This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".

The line on which it fails is:

`<handlers>`

I have a feeling that somewhere there is a setting that says that handlers cannot be overriden, but I cannot find it.

Thanks

Shiraz

Comment: what kind of developer machines do you have?  os?  iis version?

Comment: Developer machines are Windows XP, we run the solution from Visual Studio with the Cassini web server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check in `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\.` ?

Further ...

`<section name="handlers" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />`

change this value from "Deny" to "Allow"

`<section name="modules" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />`

change this value from "Deny" to "Allow"